# Combining logic statements in R's which() and ifelse() functions

Tags: r, boolean-logic

I'm always working with commands like this:

```
which(foo$bar == 'A' | foo$bar == 'B' | foo$bar == 'C')
```

Since they're all related to the same variable, I would like to be able to clean up my code and do something like this:

```
which(foo$bar == 'A|B|C')  # such syntax works in grep, why not here?
# or...
which(foo$bar == c('A', 'B', 'C'))
```

But none of this works! I'm pretty sure there's got to be a simple solution, I just can't find it. I have the same problem in `ifelse()` functions, so bonus bragging rights for a universal solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
with(foo, which(bar %in% LETTERS[1:3]) )
```

Could be used to select rows from a dataframe. It's also possible to use this as a logical index to a reporter vector, although with logical indexing you do need to remember that R indices are not 0-based.:

```
  set.seed=(123)
  foo <- data.frame(bar=sample(LETTERS[1:15], 10))
  c("Not in A|B|C", "In A|B|C") [ 1+ foo$bar %in% LETTERS[1:3] ]
```

Comment: +1 - alternate (*preferred* IMHO) design for that last bit is to store as logical: `foo$in.ABC <- foo$bar %in% LETTERS[1:3]`

Answer (score 3):

As per @baptiste

```
    mydata<-structure(list(y = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")), 
     .Names = "y", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
mydata
  y
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
5 E
```

Three solutions:

a) using `ifelse`

```
with(mydata,ifelse(y %in% c("A","B","C"),1,0))
```

b) using `which`

```
with(mydata,which(y %in% c("A","B","C")))
```

c)using `match`

```
with(mydata,match(y,c("A", "B", "C")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using logical version of `grep`:

```
foo <- letters[1:5]
foo[grepl("[a-c]", foo )]
seq_along(foo)[grepl("[a-c]", foo )]
```

Your 2nd question - is this what you're after:

```
ifelse (sum(grepl("[a-c]", foo ))==3, "abc present", "abc absent")
```

(Uses `sum` to convert logical to numeric)

Or to do something if any of the letters are present:

```
if ( any(letters[1:3] %in% foo) ) print("abc present")
```

Comment: I think the question is if any of them is present then the code will have a minor change 

    ifelse (sum(grepl("[a-c]", foo )) > 0, "abc present", "abc absent")